# BDD Cucumber Maven Junit Parralel execution not working

Tags: java, maven, bdd, cucumber-junit

I have 3 feature files each features contains of 3 tests so in total 9 tests but only 3 tests are executing and its picking up on;y 1st feature file.I have given global tag @smoke in all feature files
    Please find the pom file below.
    
        io.github.bonigarcia
        webdrivermanager
        4.0.0
    
      
    
        org.seleniumhq.selenium
        selenium-java
        3.141.59
    
        
        junit
        junit
        4.13
        test
    
    
        org.hamcrest
        hamcrest-all
        1.3
        test
    
    
        info.cukes
        cucumber-java
        1.2.5
    
        
        info.cukes
        cucumber-junit
        1.2.5
    
    
        info.cukes
        cucumber-jvm-deps
        1.0.5
        provided
    
    
        net.masterthought
        cucumber-reporting
        5.0.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
          <configuration>
          <parallel>methods</parallel>
       <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>   
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Comment: How many test methods you have in one test class? If it is just one, it would not be like you want. And so make parallel classes - not methods.

Comment: You can't excecute in parallel with that version of Cucumber. Try the most recent one (v5).

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to incorporate parallel execution feature in a Cucumber project, like:

1. `JUnit`
2. `TestNG`
3. `CLI`

but in the execution there are some differences. one of the differences is how they read the feature files and set separate threads to run the scenarios. `JUnit` (which you have used) uses one thread per feature file not per scenario or other parts in the files.

if you want all scenarios to run at once, write them in different feature files or use `TestNG` instead of `JUnit`.

more info on:
https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/